# while adding dependencies error came out in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies

I'm making my own application by android studio, navigation drawer with Kotlin.

What I want to do in this step is changing to the new layout after tapping the sidebar's value.

For that, I need to add dependencies in my Gradle script.

I searched every website that I already knew. But I couldn't find out what is wrong with this.

As I know, dependencies should be located in build.gradle(:app).

// If my information is wrong, let me know what is the correct!

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

This is my project's dependencies line.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

And This is what I changed to another code.

Please let me know what is the problem.

Comment: So what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
```

write top of the Gradle file before android {} tag

```
// default lib
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

// for kotlin
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.4'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.4'
```

I think this is enough for you to work with kotlin and jetpack components